# devexpress gridView.Rows and cells?

Tags: c#, oop, devexpress

Currently I have been using the **Devexpress Datagridview**. So I need to convert the code below into its **Devexpress Datagridview** equivalent:

```
        int id = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow row = dgvproductMenu.Rows[id];


        if (dgvproductMenu.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Update")
        {
            product ObjP = new product
            {
                Product_id = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                Name = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
                Description = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
                Price = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[5].Value),
                Uom = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString(),
                Quantity =Convert.ToInt32( row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()),
                Tax = row.Cells[8].Value.ToString()
            };
            frmAddProduct fm = new frmAddProduct(ObjP);
            fm.ShowDialog();
            this.fillGrid();
```

I want to do it with a Devexpress extension (gridview).

Comment: Why not look into devexpress documentation?

Comment: DataRow row = gdvInvoiceSummary.GetDataRow(gdvInvoiceSummary.GetSelectedRows()[0]);

            if (e.Button.Caption == "update")
            {
                invoiceSummary obj = new invoiceSummary
                {
                    //CustomerName=row.
                };

                frmAddinvoice fm = new frmAddinvoice();
                fm.ShowDialog();
            }

Comment: Perhaps start with the Obtaining and Setting Cell Values documentation: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument753

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to capture row data based on a certain even, which you have omitted from your question.  Assuming you are using a POCO/Domain Object, the way to go is to introduce a binding source and use the `.Current` property of the binding source to determine the highlighted row.

Or, if you are dead-set against that, the `.GetRow(i)` event of the grid view will return the object in row i.

From here, you can simply cast that as your POCO:

```
MyClrObject mo = (MyClrObject)bindSourceClr.Current;
```

or

```
MyClrObject mo = (MyClrObject)gridView1.GetRow(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle);
```

I think this is also a cleaner approach for your follow-up, where you are extracting the column values out.  Instead of assuming anything about the column order, you can use Intellisense to get the exact properties:

```
product ObjP = new product
{
    Product_id = MyClrObject.ProductId,
    Name = MyClrObject.Name,
    Description = MyClrObject.Description
};
```

If you are using datatables...  consider switching to domain objects.  It's not always the best way to go, but there are numerous advantages.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a clear code to get data in gridview rows for devexpress in XtragridControl.

```
  if (gridView1.RowCount >= 1)
   {
            List<PurchaseChild> purchaseChild = new List<PurchaseChild>();

            PurchaseParent purchaseParent = new PurchaseParent()
            {
                PurchaseDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtPurchaseDate.EditValue),
                PurchaseInvoice = txtInvoice.EditValue.ToString(),
                CompanyInvoice = txtCompanyInvoice.EditValue.ToString(),
                SupplyerId = cmbSupplyer.EditValue.ToString(),
                DelivaryBy = txtDelivaryBy.EditValue.ToString(),
                CreateBy = Settings.Default.UserName,
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                PcName = txtComputerName.EditValue.ToString()
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.DataRowCount; i++)
            {
             purchaseChild.Add(new PurchaseChild()
                {
            PurchaseInvoice = txtInvoice.EditValue.ToString(),
            ProductCode = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "ProductCode").ToString(),
            Qty = Convert.ToInt16(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Qty")),
            ProductPrice = Convert.ToInt16(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "ProductPrice")),
            SellingPrice = Convert.ToInt16(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "SellingPrice")),
            DiscountPrice = Convert.ToInt16(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "DiscountPrice") == null ? 0 : gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "DiscountPrice")),
            DiscountAmount = Convert.ToInt16(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "DiscountPrice") == null ? 0 : gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "DiscountAmount")),
            TotalAmount = Convert.ToInt16(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Qty")) * Convert.ToInt16(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "ProductPrice"))
                });
            }
```